# Apple ID no longer in service and cannot turn off Find My iPad

Tags: ipad

MY Apple ID has changed, as in the original one was closed and now have a new one, and I cannot sign out of some devices because it is asking for the password for the account that is now closed. How do I get around this?

Thanks.